# Error with inserting data into the database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

When I insert data into the database table, only the first letter of the data is inserted in the columns of the database.

Here are the database tables:

[image]

For the employee id:102, only the first letter of the data is inserted. This is the [Database Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6OpN.png) used.

I'm using C# in Visual Studio Community 2015 and SQL Server Studio Management Studio for my project.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TimeSheetApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeSheetAppDbConnectionString"].ToString();
            var dbcontext = new TimeSheetAppDesignDataContext(connection);

            int EmployeeID = 102;
            string EmployeeName = "Riyas", EmployeeEmailAddress = "riyas@gmail.com", EmployeeLocation = "SriLanka";
            dbcontext.insertEmployee(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeEmailAddress, EmployeeLocation);

            Console.WriteLine("Data inserted successfully");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone kindly help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you show the function `insertEmployee` ?

Comment: Right click on table->Script table as->CREATE to->New query window and post that script instead of pictures.

Comment: If that stored procedure you're using has parameters defined as `varchar` (or `nvarchar`) *without* explicitly defining a length, then those parameters default to a length of **exactly 1 character** and this would cause what you're seeing. **Solution:** you should ***always explicitly*** define a **length** when using `varchar` or `nvarchar` - no exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. I forgot to specify the length.That was the mistake.Anyway finally it is solved.

Comment: Thanks @user2185569,@Ivan Starostin for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the data correctly, and your database structure is correct. The last clue to find the error is to check the procedure `insertEmployee`, the error is in the procedure and most probably in the parameters type.

Check the parameters definition for that procedure. If you're using `NVARCHAR` without specifying the length, then the data is being truncated to a single character because the default for `NVARCHAR` is `NVARCHAR(1)`